# How to transition transform in svg

Tags: css, svg

I'm using transform attribute to translate / rotate / scale my SVG element, now I'd like to transition a changes done to my element via transform attribute. Unfortunately for some reason it doesn't work

For a test suppose you have the following markup:

```
<button onclick="change()">test</button>
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%"
  viewBox="-1 -1 100 100">
    <g>
      <rect class="rect" x="1" y="1" width="10" height="10" fill="red"  transform="translate(0 0), rotate(0)">
      </rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And the following code:

```
function change() {
  $('rect').attr('transform', 'translate(10 10), rotate(45)')
}
```

And the following css:

```
.rect {
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwOLWx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some typos in your script (no units, `attr()` instead of `css()`), use this

```
function change() {
  $('rect').css('transform', 'translate(10px, 10px) rotate(45deg)')
}
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obPdZw)

Comment: That doesn't work in Edge, only inline `transform` attribute does.

Comment: This was NOT a typo. SVG transform attribute is not the same as CSS transform property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform). So this answer is more a workaround.
MDN says that SVG transform attribute is animatable, but it seems to have no effect…